# Add delegate to event - thread safety

Tags: c#

It is possible to execute the following code from multiple threads simultaneously.

```
this._sequencer.Completed += OnActivityFinished;
```

Is it thread safe to add delegate to an event handler from multiple threads?

Is it thread safe to remove delegate to from event handler from multiple threads?

What is the simplest and maintainable way of making this thread safe?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you don’t specify your own event add/remove handlers, the C# compiler generates this **add handler** (reconstructed by [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)):

```
public void add_MyEvent(EventHandler value)
{
    EventHandler handler2;
    EventHandler myEvent = this.MyEvent;
    do
    {
        handler2 = myEvent;
        EventHandler handler3 = (EventHandler) Delegate.Combine(handler2, value);
        myEvent = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler>(ref this.MyEvent, handler3, handler2);
    }
    while (myEvent != handler2);
}
```

and a **remove handler** that looks the same but with `Delegate.Remove` instead of `Delegate.Combine`.

Notice the use of `Interlocked.CompareExchange`? This prevents a race condition between updating the event’s backing field and reading from it. Thus, it is thread-safe.

Comment: A small clarification- this is the implementation in .NET 4, Before that it used `lock(this)` (also see desco's answer)

Comment: @ohadsc I just created an event and compile against .net 2 and it still created the Interlocked code as defined by timwi

Comment: @Simon you're right, it's a compiler feature, not a runtime one. I should have said "this is the implementation in the C# 4 compiler"

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the implementation of the event, to be honest.

The field-like events generated by the C# compiler are thread-safe, but if it's a custom event, who knows?

Note that in a multi-threaded app you should expect a race condition between adding/removing a handler and the event firing... for example, the event may *start* to fire, you could then unsubscribe, and your handler would still be called after that unsubscription.

Answer (score 8):

for field-like events adding/removing of handlers is thread-safe. From spec:

> When compiling a field-like event, the compiler automatically creates storage to hold the delegate, and creates accessors for the event that add or remove event handlers to the delegate field. In order to be thread-safe, the addition or removal operations are done while holding the lock (§8.12) on the containing object for an instance event, or the type object (§7.6.10.6) for a static event.

However it is true for C# 3.0 and lesser, in C# 4.0 compiler generates lock-free implementation using Interlocked routines (but spec remains the same - bug?)

In custom implementations no one can tell exactly... except maybe the author of code :)

Comment: I believe the spec has been updated, but the updated version hasn't been published yet.

Comment: maybe, I was referring to version available here (publish date  4/19/2010) - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e&displaylang=en