# is it thread safe to register for a c# event?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

specifically, is the "+=" operation atomic?
does it make a difference if i'm using the 'event' keyword, or just a plain old delegate?

with most types, its a read, then the "+" operator, and then a write. so, it's not atomic. i'd like to know if there's a special case for delegates/events.

is this kind of code necessary, or redundant:

```
Action handler;
object lockObj;
public event Action Handler {
    add { lock(lockObj) { handler += value; } }
    remove { lock(lockObj) { handler -= value; } }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add delegate to event - thread safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522361/add-delegate-to-event-thread-safety)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `+=` and `-=` operators on ***auto implemented events*** are atomic (if a library used a custom event handler it could very easily not be atomic). From the MSDN Magazine article [.NET Matters: Event Accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx)

> When the C# compiler generates code for MyClass, the output
>   Microsoft® Intermediate Language (MSIL) is identical in behavior to
>   what would have been produced using code like that in Figure 1.
>
> **Figure 1 Expanded Event Implementation**
>
> ```
> class MyClass
> {
>     private EventHandler _myEvent;
>
>     public event EventHandler MyEvent
>     {
>         [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
>         add 
>         { 
>             _myEvent = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(_myEvent, value);
>         }
>         [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
>         remove 
>         { 
>             _myEvent = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(_myEvent, value); 
>         }
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Another use for explicit event implementation is to provide a custom
>   synchronization mechanism (or to remove one). **You'll notice in Figure
>   1 that both the add and remove accessors are adorned with a
>   MethodImplAttribute that specifies that the accessors should be
>   synchronized.** For instance events, this attribute is equivalent to
>   wrapping the contents of each accessor with a lock on the current
>   instance:
>
> ```
> add { lock(this) _myEvent += value; } 
> remove { lock(this) _myEvent -= value; }
> ```

Comment: +1, a great example of why to avoid locking on state objects like `lock (_eventSource) { ... }`.

Comment: What about when calling `MyEvent?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty)` How is the backing InvocationList threadsafe? (which doesn't have access to your lock object)

Comment: The invokation list is immutable in that context. Once the Invoke is called it will call all handlers that where attached at point in time.

Answer (score 3):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522556/120955), the `add` handler is auto-implemented in a thread-safe way that will perform better than a lock.

What you need to be more careful of, when it comes to thread-safety on events, is how you invoke them. See Eric Lippert's post on this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx).

> The standard pattern for firing this event is:
>
> ```
> Action temp = Foo;
> if (temp != null)
>       temp();
> ```