# Event is called after unsubscription

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling

I'm using an object (`EventReceiver`) that registers a member to an event of an object (`EventSource`) imported via ctor. The `EventReceiver`implements `IDisposable` and unsubscribes itself from the `EventSource`.

The problem is that there are different threads that invoke the event handler and disposes the `EventReceiver`. The event will be called after the unsubscribe is done. There's a race condidition between event raising and unsubscribing.

How could that be solved?

Here's a sample implementation that demonstrates the problem:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var eventSource = new EventSource();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        eventSource.RaiseEvent();
                    }
                });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        new EventReceiver(eventSource).Dispose();
                    }
                });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class EventSource
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SampleEvent;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        var handler = this.SampleEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public class EventReceiver : IDisposable
{
    private readonly EventSource _source;

    public EventReceiver(EventSource source)
    {
        this._source = source;
        this._source.SampleEvent += this.OnSampleEvent;
    }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

    private void OnSampleEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (this.IsDisposed)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This should never happen...");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._source.SampleEvent -= this.OnSampleEvent;
        this.IsDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

The exception will be thrown nearly direct after program start on a multi core processor. Yes I know that `var handler = this.SampleEvent` will create a copy of the event handler and that causes the problem.

I tried to implement the `RaiseEvent` method like that but it doesn't help:

```
public void RaiseEvent()
{
    try
    {
        this.SampleEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

The question is: How to implement threadsafe registering to and unregistering from events in a multithreaded manner?

My expectation was that the unregistering will be suspended until the current fired event has been finished (meybe this could only work using the second implementation). But I was disappointed.

Comment: Looks like `OnSampleEvent` and `Dispose` should be synchronized by mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got two threads - one calling the event handlers, and one unsubscribing - there will *always* be a race condition, where you end up with the following ordering:

- Event-raiser starts to raise the event
- Event-unsubscriber unsubscribes
- Event-raiser executes handler

That's inevitable with the immutability of delegates in .NET. Even with some sort of thread-safe, mutable delegate type there'd always be a finer-grained race condition:

- Event-raiser starts to raise the event
- Event-raiser starts to execute handler - but it hasn't yet got to the first line of user code
- Event-unsubscriber unsubscribes
- Handler executes user code

Worse, you could unsubscribe *while* the handler is executing - what would you expect to happen then? Would you expect the handler code to be arbitrarily terminated?

You can easily implement your own check for "am I really meant to run at this point" within the handler, but you'll need to work out your own semantics. You *could* use locking to make sure that the handler unsubscription can't occur *while* the handler is executing, but that feels pretty dangerous to me, unless you know that your event handler will complete in a short time frame.

Comment: Yes you're dead on - but i knew that already. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522361/add-delegate-to-event-thread-safety) shows that (un)registering events is threadsafe. But why when it's impossible to raise the event correctly. I try to use a lock to synchronize the event handler and the unsubscribtion - but I'm still locking for a better solution.

Comment: @Verarind: Your options really are just "lock to avoid concurrent unsubscribe/execute" or "accept that concurrent unsubscribe/execute may happen". It's not a matter of being "impossible to raise the event correctly" - it's a matter of there fundamentally not being a good definition of that.